# Duplicate panel since LTS upgrade

Tags: gnome, panel

I have finally moved to the new Gnome 3 LTS 18.04 
however i seem to have kept a version of the unity launcher panel along with the dock to dash gnome 3 panel.  It mirrors what i do so if i add or remove an app from the dash it gets added or removed from both.  How do i get rid of the vertical one to the LHS? ive tried all the tweak settings but it removes both panels if i deselect.[image: Screenshot from 2019-11-13 10-23-10.png]

Comment: You apparently have a range of extensions installed. Disable them all, log out then back in, and enable, one by one, only those that you understand what they do, and that provide that functionality that you want.